# How to exlude a form field in a django view

Tags: django, forms

I am using Django 1.9.5
I am using a form in my view.
I will use same form in forms.py for GET and POST in my view.
I want to exclude one field if it is GET.
I want it to show all fields if it is POST.
I dont want to use 2 different forms in forms.py for the same view.

```
Views.py

method = 'GET'
mine_form = MineForm(prefix='mine', method=method)

Forms.py

class MineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=False)
    re_password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput, label='Re-type Password', required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Mine
        exclude = []
        widgets = {
            'gender': forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer),
            'uuid': forms.HiddenInput(),
        }
        exclude = ['user', ]

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.method = kwargs.pop('method', None)
            super(MineForm).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            if self.method == 'GET':
                self.fields.pop('delete_mine')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply delete the field from the `fields` dict if it's a GET request:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    del self.fields["yourField"]
```

Comment: Where do i do this ? in views.py or in forms.py ?

Comment: In the views.py file

Comment: It says  "global name 'self' is not defined"

Comment: replace self with your form

Comment: for clarity, in view `GET` is the `else:` part of `if request.method == "POST":`